# Matlab `quantile` doesn't interpolate between sample values on ECDF?

Tags: matlab, quantile, ecdf

According to [Matlab's help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/quantiles-and-percentiles.html), `quantile` interpolates linearly between points on the empirical cumulative distribution function (ECDF).  Importantly, the points interpolated between are the [mid-points of the risers at each step](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/quantiles-and-percentiles.html).  I'm finding the actual behaviour to be significantly different.  Here is my example, the ECDF, and a line segment to show the interpolation:

```
y= [ 1 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 9 10 ]
ecdf(y)
grid on
set(get(gca,'Children'),'LineWidth',2)
hold on

% Line segment for interpolation
x2points=[2;5]; y2points=[0.15;0.5];
plot(x2points,y2points)
```

[image]

From the interpolation line segment, we would expect the quantile for F(x)=0.3 to be around x=3.3, but instead, it is x=5.

```
yInterior=0.3 % Value to get `x` for
xInterior=interp1(y2points,x2points,yInterior) % ans = 3.2857
xInterior=quantile(y,yInterior) % ans x=5
```

Is there another piece of documentation elsewhere that I'm missing which explains this difference?

Am I the only one seeing this?

I'm using Matlab 2015b.

Comment: I get `3.4` on R2016b and on R2017b

Comment: OK, thanks, Luis.  It means that `quantile` on 2015b hasn't caught up with its own documentation on 2015b.  ** Sigh **.  I'll wait a bit for other responses before posting this as the explanation.  P.S. Interesting to note that LaTeX notation is not recognized in this forum.

Comment: Note also that you may not be interpreting the interpolation correctly (but that doesn't explain the value you get). From the linked doc: `quantile(y, 2.5/9)` should give `3`, `quantile(3.5/9)` should give `5`, and `quantile(y, .3)` should give `.8*3+.2*5` = `3.4` because `.3` equals `.8*2.5/9+.2*3.5/9`

Comment: I don't quite follow where you get the fractions for `quantile`'s second argument, but my interpretation of interpolation comes from the Matlab's "Quantiles and Percentiles" page, which is linked to from the `quantile` help page.  It's the same information as for 2015b.  Does that address your point about properly interpreting interpolation?

Comment: I get those fractions from [`quantile`'s doc page](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/quantiles-and-percentiles.html), item 1, right at the top of the page. For those values there is no need to interpolate, as the quantiles are directly values from `y`. Then, the interpolation is done with (in this case) the coefficients `.8` and `.2`; this is item 2 on that page. So the correct result is `3.4`, not `3.5`

Comment: I complicated the problem by choose a sample whose ECDF doesn't lie on the grid lines.  Will change it...Thanks.